# Panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference only on the GAE

Tags: go, google-app-engine, go-gin

I am working on the golang app using gin framework. Basically it just fetch the data from firestore as JSON.

Localy it works perfectly but when I deploy it to the GAE (gcloud app deploy) there is no error during deployment but when access the page it does not work and in the logs provide an error: "panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference"

package listcollections

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "cloud.google.com/go/firestore"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "google.golang.org/api/iterator"
    "google.golang.org/appengine"
)

func main() {

}

//GetListCollections function

func GetListCollections(c *gin.Context) {

    var coll []string
    ctx := appengine.NewContext(c.Request)

    projectID := "XXX"
    client, err := firestore.NewClient(ctx, projectID)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to create client: %v", err)
    }
    defer client.Close()

    iter := client.Collection("collection").Documents(ctx)

    for {

        doc, err := iter.Next()

        if err == iterator.Done {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("ERROR")
        }

        coll = append(coll, doc.Data()["Title"].(string))

    }

    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
        "collections": coll,
    })

}
```

Comment: You should _at_ _least_ indicate at which line your code fails.

Comment: You are not handling the error returned by iter.Next. You only print it and then carry on as if nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

As no one has any clue where it did happen?

From Analysing your code, the only possibility which I can think off is that your 
`itr` variable is empty.

You might need to change the check for error part and add Panic instead of just printing the error and keep runing

```golang
        if err != nil {
            panic("ERROR")
        }
```

Comment: The issue is exactly in  if err != nil {
            panic("ERROR")
        } but it works locally and not when deployed to GAE

Comment: Now i have an error in GAE: panic: rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = Missing or insufficient permissions